# What are psychologically good methods of learning the language?

Tags: motivation, learning-psychology

I am developing a website for learning foreign language and first idea which came to my mind is to open courses where people learn grammar and put correct words as well as correct articles. Also some lessons for vocabulary will be available. I've read something that those kind of methods of learning a foreign language might be dry and not very motivational for newcomers and should be designed more interactive involving a private tutor or at least artificial intelligence which will guide through the learning proccess. What are in bullet points 3 most important psychologically good methods to learn the language and motivate newcomers to start and keep being motivated over a long period of time?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.